# Merge [semmle-ql] into [codeql]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

[Semmle](https://semmle.com/), which provided *Semmle QL*, [was acquired by GitHub](https://blog.semmle.com/secure-software-github-semmle/) in 2019. The technology has been integrated into GitHub Advanced Security code scanning and is now called *[CodeQL](https://codeql.github.com/)*.

I'm a product manager at GitHub for the CodeQL analysis engine, and for the purposes of our teams tracking and evaluating questions on Stack Overflow, I propose to merge [semmle-ql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/semmle-ql) into the [codeql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codeql) tag.

Adding a wiki entry for the tag to point people to the right resources is a secondary step we intend to perform later.